# Area 51 proposal invitation notification

Tags: discussion, area-51, notifications

I've now twice gotten the following notification on Area 51:

> Welcome to Stack Exchange Area 51!
>
> **user** thought you'd be interested in this proposed Q&A site. If you like
>   the idea, you can click the "Commit"
>   button below to be notified when the
>   site is created.

both for a proposal that I was already committed to. How do these notifications work, how can I send them myself? And are they only displayed if you visit that specific proposal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a referral.

To refer an user to a a proposal, you just have click the `Share This` button under the `Commit` or `Follow` button of the proposal. This is will give you a link with your referral ID. Anyone that arrives to the proposal through that link will get that notification and earn you reputation if they commit or follow.

For some reason I don't understand, you *have* to at least follow the proposal to be able to refer. Otherwise, the `Share This` button won't be there.

Comment: Aha! I must have followed some referral links without noticing it. Some of the links to the proposals in the discussion area must be referral links.

Comment: @Fabian: That's correct. If you're going to drop a link, why not make it a referral link for the same chance that it earns you some extra reputation?